# Edit All feature not working - CakePHP

Tags: loops, cakephp, foreach, edit

I am working on a feature to edit all the items in the table.

Here is my edit action from my controller:

```
public function editAll()
    {
        $this->set('isEditAllValid', false);
        $this->set('editAllValidationErrors', false);

        if ($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            $this->LocalClock->table = 'local_clocks';
            $this->LocalClock->getDataSource()->tableFields['local_clocks'] = array( "id", "name", "auto_offset", "utc_offset_sec", "in_month", "in_week", "in_day", "in_hour", "out_month", "out_week", "out_day", "out_hour", "offset_sec");
            $this->set('localClocksEntries', $this->LocalClock->find('all'));
            if ($this->LocalClock->save($this->request->data))
            {
                foreach($localClocksEntries as $LocalClock)
                {
                    $this->set('LocalClock', $this->request->data);
                    $this->LocalClock->save($LocalClock);
                    $this->set('isEditAllValid', true);
                    $this->set('editAllValidationErrors', false);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->set('isEditAllValid', false);
                $this->set('editAllValidationErrors', true);
            }
        }
    }
```

What I am doing in the code is, set some boolean variables to false (validation stuff), then if the action is a post grab the local clocks table and insert that into a variable for storage.  Then loop through that variable  and save the data that was posted to each item in the table.

I don't know why but I am getting2 errors when trying to edit all.

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: localClocksEntries   [APP/Controller/LocalClocksController.php, line 158]
>   Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach()   [APP/Controller/LocalClocksController.php, line 158]

Basically I just want to loop through every row in the table and change the contents to what the user entered in the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->set('localClocksEntries', $this->LocalClock->find('all'));
```

This sets a variable *for the view*. It does not create that variable in the current scope. So the variable `$localClocksEntries` does not exist in `foreach ($localClocksEntries ...`. If you want to use the variable in the current scope *and* pass it on to the view, do:

```
$localClocksEntries = $this->LocalClock->find('all');
$this->set('localClocksEntries', $localClocksEntries);
```

Comment: I made the change and I don't get those errors.  But when trying to save it ends up adding a new item to the table and not editing the existing items. Any ideas?

Comment: The primary key (id) needs to be set for each iteration in the loop. If the ID isn't specified, cake will create a new row instead of editing one.

Comment: @Hoff - I got it working, thanks for the help.
I just added these two lines to solve that and it worked.
`$this->LocalClock->id = $LocalClock['LocalClock']['id'];
$this->LocalClock->save($this->request->data);`